# .keystore file is generated as part of moving my webapplication on https?

Tags: java, https, digital-certificate

i am trying to get my application on https instead of http. i installed **Win32 OpenSSL v0.9.8t Light**  from http://www.slproweb.com/products/Win32OpenSSL.html As per documentation i  ran the command **keytool -import -keystore jre\lib\security\cacerts -alias fipOpenSSLCert -file %OPENSSL_HOME%\private\cacert.cer** under java_home/bin and after completion it says Certificate was added to keystore and CAKey.pem,CACert.pem and CACert.cer are generated but no  .keystore file was generated which we mention inserver.xml of tomcat. I am note is it necessary or which step i missed. Any clues will be a great help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> [If you don't specify a `-keystore` option, the default keystore is a file named `.keystore` **in your home directory**. If that file does not yet exist, it will be created.](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.3/docs/tooldocs/win32/keytool.html#KeystoreLoc)

Comment: As per link you mentioned it says More specifically, if you specify, in the -keystore option, a keystore that doesn't yet exist, that keystore will be created. But what will be the file name in this case and where it will be created. I searched in my whole computer i did not find any file with name keystore

Comment: Either specify the filename with `-keystore` *`path/to/keystore/filename`*, or if you don't specify the filename, the keystore is created *in your home directory* with the name `.keystore` *(leading dot)*, probably `C:\Documents and Settings\MSach\.keystore`.